# CKeditor TextArea not visible in Juniper VPN

Tags: ckeditor

Upgraded CKeditor to 4.5.3.

**CKeditor TextArea not visible in Juniper VPN**
(it works inside network)

When I compared two html sources, found out editor control is not getting created
while we access the site via SSL VPN (juniper)
following code is not there in view source in VPN access

I have been trying to resolve this issue past week.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Shiva